# Objects appear deformed in Object mode but normal in Edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view, vertices

At first I thought it was the mirror clipping causing it, but I deleted the modifier entirely and it wasn't fixed. Then i thought it might have been caused by "rogue" edges that were on the "empty" side of the objects, but deleting them didn't yield any result. Any ideas?
This is my very first time using Blender, or 3D modeling in general btw.

Comment: It looks like a shadow issue.

Comment: Please add a screenshot, it will greatly help you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have any "shape key" active or configured.

check screenshot:

[image]